# Apache Camel spring splitter parallel processing with aggregrator xml is not working as like of Java DSL

Tags: java, apache-camel

What would be equivalent xml for the below java DSL, please suggest

```
 public class OrderRouter1 extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    from("direct:processOrder")
        .split(body().method("getItems"), new OrderItemStrategy())
        .parallelProcessing()
        .to("direct:processItem")
     .end();


    from("direct:processItem")
        .choice()
            .when(body().method("getType").isEqualTo("Book"))
                .to("bean:itemService?method=processBook").
            otherwise()
                .to("bean:itemService?method=processPhone");
}
```

}

I tried using the below xml configuration, without using aggregator, but when i am enabling parallelprocessing, it is working sequentially.

```
 <camelContext id="orderCtx" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
   <route>
        <from uri="direct:processOrder" />
        <split parallelProcessing="true">
        <simple>${body}</simple>
            <to uri="direct:processItem" />
        </split>

    </route>

    <route>
        <from uri="direct:processItem" />
            <bean beanType="com.apache.camel.aggregrator.ItemSvc" method="processBook"/>
            <bean beanType="com.apache.camel.aggregrator.ItemSvc" method="processPhone"/>
        </route>


</camelContext>
```

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest the following change to the upper route "processOrder"

```
<split parallelProcessing="true">
    <simple>${body.getItems}</simple>
    <to uri="direct:processItem" />
</split>
```

if you want to use your AggregationStrategy again, you could add `strategyRef="yourBean"` to the splitter

Comment: Thanks Japu, yeah i can add it and check, but my problem is with the xml configuration i need to make it work as like how java dsl is working in parallel

Comment: you should try it, i think it was splitting sequentielly, because you didn't called the `getItems()` Method in your Spring-Camelcontext and therefore you tried to split the whole body - which is probably not splittable and therefore gets passed on as is

Comment: Yes. I tried to look at the documentation how we can write it in xml, but not able to get right links to follow or read.

Comment: @MadhusudhanGRevankar maybe worth a look http://camel.apache.org/simple.html#Simple-OGNLexpressionsupport

Comment: after the above changes, still its working sequentially <split parallelProcessing="true" strategyRef="orderItemStrategy" >
    <simple>${body.getItems}</simple>
    <to uri="direct:processItem" />
   </split>

Comment: did the before mentioned Java DSL solution work sequentially? and how do you determine if it is not really working in parallel - just because the items get processed sequentially does not mean they can't be processed in parallel. it could just be coincidence that one after the other finishes. or are you 100% certain that the first gets processed and then finishes and only after that the next one is processed?

Comment: yeah, i have added some delay in one process. With DSL way its working perfectly as it is not working sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i was able to get the equivalent java DSL to XML and its working as expected

```
<bean id="orderItemStrategy" class="com.apache.camel.aggregrator.OrderItemStrategy" />
<bean id="itemService" class="com.apache.camel.aggregrator.ItemSvc" />
<camelContext id="orderCtx" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="direct:processOrder" />
        <split parallelProcessing="true" strategyRef="orderItemStrategy">
            <simple>${body.getItems}</simple>
            <to uri="direct:processItem" />
        </split>
    </route>
    <route>
        <from uri="direct:processItem" />
         <choice>
        <when>
            <simple>${body.getType} == 'Book'</simple>
           <to uri="bean:itemService?method=processBook" />
        </when>
         <otherwise>
           <to uri="bean:itemService?method=processPhone" />
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```